# Как сделать так, чтобы при открытии меню фон опускался под меню?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

При клике на гамбургер открывается меню. Фоновое изображение при открытии меню должно опускаться под это меню, но не полностью, а чтобы верхняя часть картинки перекрывалась. На скрине понятнее, как это должно выглядеть.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var navMain = document.querySelector('.main-nav');
var navToggle = document.querySelector('.main-nav__toggle');
navMain.classList.remove('main-nav--opened')

navMain.classList.remove('main-nav--nojs');

navToggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (navMain.classList.contains('main-nav--closed')) {
    navMain.classList.remove('main-nav--closed');
    navMain.classList.add('main-nav--opened');
  } else {
    navMain.classList.add('main-nav--closed');
    navMain.classList.remove('main-nav--opened');
  }
});
```

```css
.page-header {
  min-height: 461px;
  background-image: url("https://s1.1zoom.ru/b5050/596/281190-Sepik_1400x1050.jpg");
}

.main-nav {
  position: relative;

  width: 100%;

  background-color: #283645;
 }
 
 .main-nav__toggle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  right: -5px;
  top: -50px;

  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-right: 6%;
 }
 
 .main-nav--closed .main-nav__toggle::before {
  content: "";

  position: absolute;
  right: 1px;
  top: 2px;

  width: 50px;
  height: 24px;

  background-color: red;
}

.main-nav--opened .main-nav__toggle::after {
  content: "";

  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: -1px;

  width: 24px;
  height: 23px;

  background-color: green;
 }
 
 .main-nav--closed .main-nav__item {
    display: none;
  }

  .main-nav--nojs .main-nav__toggle {
    display: none;
  }

  .main-nav--nojs .main-nav__wrapper {
    position: static;
    min-height: 0;
  }

  .main-nav--nojs .main-nav__item {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .main-nav--closed .main-nav__list::after {
  display: none;
}

.main-nav--opened .main-nav__list {
  min-height: 255px;
}

.main-nav__list {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

.main-nav__item {
  position: relative;

  padding-top: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;

  text-align: center;
}

.main-nav__link {
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 31px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  }
```

```html
<header class="page-header page-header--prime">
      <div class="page-header__logo-link-color">
        <a class="page-header__logo-link">
          <svg></svg>
        </a>
      </div>
      <nav class="main-nav main-nav--opened main-nav--closed main-nav--nojs">
        <button class="main-nav__toggle" type="button">
        </button>
        <ul class="main-nav__list">
          <li class="main-nav__item main-nav__item--active">
            <a class="main-nav__link main-nav__link--active">Главная</a>
          </li>
          <li class="main-nav__item">
            <a class="main-nav__link" href="photo.html">Фотографии</a>
          </li>
          <li class="main-nav__item">
            <a class="main-nav__link" href="form.html">Конкурс</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: Простите, что?.

Comment: Необходимо, чтобы при открытии меню фон опускался под это меню.

Comment: у вас же там не только фон опускается, а весь контент, соответственно задавать при открытии нужный `padding-top` хедеру, а если только фон, то `background-position`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать такой вариант: Сделать меню с нулевой высотой между основным контентом шапки и секцией под ней. Обернуть все это в обертку, которой задать фоновую картинку и расположить ее по нижнему краю блока. По клику на ссылку увеличивать высоту меню, которое будет отталкивать вниз секцию, увеличивая общую высоту блока обертки и смещая (визуально) фон вниз т.к. он прибит к нижней границе блока обертки.

```js
var header = document.getElementById('header');
var link = document.getElementById('menu_link');

link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 header.classList.toggle('collapsed');
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background: url("https://s1.1zoom.ru/b5050/596/281190-Sepik_1400x1050.jpg") no-repeat center 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
}

header {
  background: rgba(40, 54, 69, 0.9);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.header_content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.collapsed {
  background: rgba(40, 54, 69, 1);
}

.collapsed .menu {
  max-height: 200px;
}

li {
  background: #283645;
  color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

section {
  height: 300px;
  padding: 30px 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu_link {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header id="header">
    <div class="header_content">
      <a href="#" class="menu_link" id="menu_link">Меню</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="menu" id="menu">
      <li>Ссылка</li>
      <li>Ссылка</li>
      <li>Ссылка</li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  
  <section>
    Контент
  </section>
</div>
```

Накидал на глаз, примерную структуру, дальше уже по аналогии сделаете свой вариант.